# TypeScript: Difference in check

Tags: typescript

What is the difference between

```
export function hasValue<T>(val?: T | null): boolean {
    return val !== null && val !== undefined;
}
```

and

```
export function hasValue<T>(val?: T | null): val is T {
    return val !== null && val !== undefined;
}
```

What exactly means `val is T` here?

Comment: It's a *type predicate*, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second version of the function is a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). The important difference is, that within a scope of a type guard, the type of the value is assumed the guarded type. In `val is T`, the `T` is the guarded type.

For example:

```
export function hasValue<T>(val?: T | null): val is T {
    return val !== null && val !== undefined;
}

var value: int | null; //<-- value has type int | null;

if (hasValue(value)) {
   var isPositive = value > 0; //<-- within the scope of the type guard, value has type int
}
else {
    //Within this scope, value is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's quickly run through both functions...

This version of `hasValue` returns either true or false, that's what the return type annotation `: boolean` is doing:

```
export function hasValue<T>(val?: T | null): boolean {
    return val !== null && val !== undefined;
}
```

In this next version, we have a custom type guard. The return type annotation has been upgraded from `: boolean` to `: val is T`. This literally means "if I return `true`, it means that the argument `val` is of type `T`".

```
export function hasValue<T>(val?: T | null): val is T {
    return val !== null && val !== undefined;
}
```

You can use the function to narrow types. Demo below:

```
class Customer {
    constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string) { }
}

let x: Customer | null;

if (hasValue<Customer>(x)) {
    // In here, we have proved x is Customer, not null
    const example = x.firstName;
} else {
    // Error - firstName does not exist, because we have proved x is null or undefined
    const example = x.firstName;
}
```